# How to make Ansible execute bash code on all 6 of my compute nodes, instead of 5 and then 1?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible on a head node to communicate to 6 compute nodes. I set up my Ansible `/etc/ansible/hosts` to indicate the IP addresses of my 6 compute nodes. I then pass commands through Ansible such as the following:

`ansible all -m shell -a "sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor" -u root`

However, the first 5 compute nodes return the necessary information, but then there is a pause and finally the sixth node returns as well. I've played with the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file, and have found that it is always the last IP address of the 6 listed that has the pause; it doesn't matter which compute node we are talking about.

If I run a computationally intensive command, such as finding prime numbers through ansible, the first 5 commands occur simultaneously, and the final command execute only after the first 5 have completed. What is going on? Why can I not send the command to all nodes simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-f` parameter to specify the number of parallel processes to use.

```
ansible all -m shell -a "sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor" -u root -f 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. Ansible comes with a default setting of parallel forks set at 5. You can change this in the `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` file. I changed it to 6, and now everything works great.